# How to show a text widget when a screen is not calling data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, widget

I have the activity screen that gets data from Firebase, I'm trying to show a text message like "No activities yet" when the database is not providing data.

I tried to use a ternary operator condition that checks if the database is empty and it works, however, the problem is that when I go the activity screen and it has data, it still shows the message for about 1 second and then shows the activity screen, so, I would like to know if there is a better way to implement this.

Hope this makes sense.

**See the code below**

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => _setupActivities(),
        child: _activities.isEmpty
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Aun no Tienes Notificaciones',
                  style: ktextTitlesStyle.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: responsive.height(context) / 50),
                ),
                )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _activities.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Activity activity = _activities[index];
                  return _buildActivity(activity);
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

}

Comment: so your `_activities` is a list? you fetch data from from Firebase then put the data in your `_activities` or what?

Comment: yes, it is a list, that is correct, every time a user get a like, that data is saved in the database and then fetch that data into the activity screen, if a user does not get any likes, the activity screen will be blank and that's exactly the problem,  I want to show the user something while the activity screen is empty but I have the problem that when they go to the activity screen and it has data, it still shows the message that I mentioned above for about 1 or 2 seconds and then shows the activity screen, I want that message to only shows where there no data.

Comment: i think using `StreamBuilder()` might help

Comment: why that would work with StreamBuilder()? I don't see why I would need a StreamBuilder

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but checking for *.hasData* on the *AsyncSnapshot* might help determine if data is returned.

```
Container( child: FutureBuilder(future: someFutureFirebaseDataReturningMethod(), builder: (context, snapshot) { 
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return _noActiviesYet();
    return _showActivies(snapshot, context);
}))
```

*.hasData* returns "whether this snapshot contains a non-null data value."(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html)